# SQL Insert statement not working C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Using Access database like this :

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Resources/cars_db.accdb");
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Email, Address, Question, Answer) VALUES ('" + txtUsernameRP.Text + "','" + txtPasswordRP.Text + "','" + txtEmailRP.Text + "','" + txtAddressRP.Text + "','" + txtQuestionRP.Text + "','" + txtAnswerRP.Text + "')";
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); -- **Breaks here and says syntax error**
```

I have tried:

1. Taking out the int i bit.
2. Putting the @ symbol in front of the statement.
3. Checked and made sure that I am using the Access code.
4. Tried closing the connection before creating in case it was something there.
5. Substituted the data for fixed values, which I then ran in a query in Access which worked.
6. Put the access query mentioned above into the code block ***(cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Email, Address, Question, Answer) VALUES ('asdasd','Asd!23asd','asdasd','asdasd','asdasd','asdasd')";*** and tried running it and again same syntax error.

Please someone help me...

Comment: Do you have any specific syntax error (near line ...) ? Or just general syntax error?

Comment: You missed a paranteces in nr 6. i dont know if it matters but...

Comment: As per your query generated '(' is missing after Users.

Comment: So, why did you add **MySQL** tag if you use **Access**?

Comment: firstly check the code block up top. that is the code in my program.

Comment: can you put semicolon ";" at the end of sql query and try again once ?

Comment: only says syntax error in insert statement

Comment: @DanielStackenland he missed it only in comment but code is correct

Comment: @ naveen Still broken after inserting semicolon

Comment: Did you try this request outside your code?

Comment: @ alex - yes I pasted it into a access query that allows sql code and it worked perfectly

Comment: On an unrelated note, *you don't save passwords as plain text in a database!*. Use a hash function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password is reserved keyword

```
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Email, Address...
```

try this

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, [Password], Email, Address...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can You try this?

```
 "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Email, Address, Question, Answer) 
    VALUES(
    '" + txtUsernameRP.Text + "',
    '" + txtPasswordRP.Text + "',
    '" + txtEmailRP.Text + "',
    '" + txtAddressRP.Text + "',
    '" + txtQuestionRP.Text + "',
    '" + txtAnswerRP.Text + "');";
```

Comment: I have tried removing "(Username, Password, Email, Address, Question, Answer)" and it works fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is on that `int i`, try removing it